# Yii2-usuario: extending login process

Tags: php, yii2, user-management

Working with Yii2-usuario, I want to extend the login process by setting some session variables AFTER the user has logged in successfully.

I tried extending the User model by:

replacing the User class in `./config/web.php`:

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => Da\User\Module::class,
        'classMap' => [
            'User' => app\models\user\User::class,
        ],
    ],
],
```

and overloading the `User`class in `./models/users/User.php`:

```
namespace app\models\user;
use Da\User\Model\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function login(IdentityInterface $identity, $duration = 0)
    {
        $ok = parent::login();
        myNewFeature();
        return $ok;
    }
}
```

as stated in the [docs](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/enhancing-and-overriding/overriding-classes/).

BUT: this `login()` function never gets executed when a user logs in.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to utilize the events provided by the extension. If you look into the [FormEvents](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events/form-events/) you see the following under the `SecurityController` heading

- `FormEvent::EVENT_BEFORE_LOGIN`: Occurs before a user logs into the system
- `FormEvent::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN`: Occurs after a user logs into the system

So what you need to do is to define an event and add your code there, the docs say to create a file named `events.php` inside your `config` folder and then load it into your entry script.

Here is an example of setting an event for the `SecurityController`:

```
<?php 
// events.php file

use Da\User\Controller\SecurityController;
use Da\User\Event\FormEvent;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(SecurityController::class, FormEvent::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $form = $event->getForm();

    // ... your logic here
});
```

and then the last part is to load this file in your entry script

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

require(__DIR__ . '/../config/events.php'); // <--- adding events here! :)

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

Comment: sorry off topic, but any idea on how to fix this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375873/yii2-usuario-custom-fields-in-social-connect-page